# What is the best approach to handle dynamically generated unique DOMs on a page based on a common single template?

Tags: php, jquery, html

<strike>Suppose you have a page in which users can create a new, unique div every time they click a button. The content of the div is mostly based on a common single template on the server side, but as the user can create several of these, the content DOMs ids of the resulting div have to be dynamically generated for each request, so as to be able to select each individual div and its content separately through jQuery afterwards (otherwise, since these divs are based on the same template, they would naturally always have the same DOM Ids, thus making it impossible to select them individually using jQuery)</strike>

Let's say you are building a windows system with javascript and jquery. On the server side you have one template that represents the "folder" window; this template has its own buttons, menus, etc, all of them being dom elements with their ID.

The user is then, on the page, supposed to be able to open several "folder" windows, each of which is assigned a different id on its creation, but the contents are the same, since the template loaded is the same for all of these windows. That is to say, provided the user opens 3 "folder" windows, the actual markup loaded in the page may look like the following:

```
<div id="firstWindow">
    <div id="windowContainer">
        <div id="windowHead">
            stuff
        </div>
        <div id="windowBody">
            <div id="windowInfoButton">stuff</div>
            stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="secondWindow">
    <div id="windowContainer">
        <div id="windowHead">
            stuff
        </div>
        <div id="windowBody">
            <div id="windowInfoButton">stuff</div>
            stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="thirdWindow">
    <div id="windowContainer">
        <div id="windowHead">
            stuff
        </div>
        <div id="windowBody">
            <div id="windowInfoButton">stuff</div>
            stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see windowContainer, windowHead, etc are duplicated as a result of reading from the same template. By itself this is already bad, but moreover I need to be able to select each windowContainer or windowHead using jQuery in such a way that manipulating them in firstWindow doesn't affect secondWindow, so simply switching all ids to classes wouldn't do it.

There are two approaches I can think to solve this:

1) Since I'm using PHP directly as the templating language, I could easily attach some code that generates a randomid or string and replace every DOM e.g. from this:

```
<div id="someFixedID" class="someClass">stuff</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="<?=$someRandomStuff?>someFixedID" class="someClass">stuff</div>
```

The problem is that, well, if the template has some 20 or 30 DOM elements, that would greatly pollute it, and I'm trying to have as little code in the templates as possible to be able to quickly iterate on the design.

2) Using jQuery, it's possible to load the template via ajax, loop through every element in the div and change their ids on the fly before showing it. This would help keeping the templates clean, but I'm concerned this method may add an unnecesary overhead on the client side, since it may have to loop through some 20 or 30 elements.

Which method would make more sense in terms of maintainability and performance? Is there another way to approach this I didn't think of?

Comment: For what reason do you need the id (or a unique id) in this example?

Comment: I would like to animate some of the contents of the generated div using jQuery after the user creates it, but for that I need to select the specific div and its contents since I don't want *all* created divs to animate when a new one is created

Comment: Ok, more specifically, it's not just animation right after the div is created, but the specific div itself should also be able to respond to some events, such as the press of some buttons, something which is controlled by jQuery selectors aswell

Comment: You will have a reference to it when you create it though: `var d = $('<div/>');`, right? I think explaining what you actually plan to do (your entire flow) would be beneficial

Comment: Just commented again, see previous comment; in a nutshell I need to individually select them not only after they are created but also to fire events later on

Comment: If the newly created `div` is always at the end of your HTML, you can try `$('div').last()` to reference it to `animate` and `bind` code to its events. If you show us the actual HTML and JS and say what you're expecting specifically THEN we might be able to help you better.

Comment: You can target these elements individually by using an index to access them, e.g. `$('.someClass').eq(0)`. I'm still not sure how adding a random id to the div will help you select it.

Comment: Just add an interative number to each 'someFixedId'. Having '1someFixedId' up through '25someFixedId' can't pollute the code *that* much, can it?

Comment: Actually, come to think of it I may just be able to attach all the relevant events right after the specific div is created where I still have the reference. I'm going to give that a try and come back at you with a better explanation if it doesn't work out.

Comment: It seems jQuery binds events to the id, and isn't really able to handle cases of duplicate ids, even if you define the relevant events on the creation of each div. I'll go ahead and update the question with more detail.

Comment: Done. Let me know if the explanation is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem you need to create a `DIV` dynamically with a unique id. Add `DIV`s with unique `ID`s using jQuery and then load content from server side in these `DIV`s. You need to synchronize your client side `ID`s generate code with server side template names/content.

**For Example:**

**HTML**:

```
<div id='container'></div>
<input type='button' name='create' value='create' id='create'>​
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#create').live( 'click', function(){   
    var num = $('div.mydiv').length;
    var html = '<div id="myid' + num + '" class="mydiv">My Content ' + num + '</div>';
    $('#container').append(html);       
});​
```

[Try Here](http://jsfiddle.net/YHgrb/)

May be not a perfect solution but hope it will give you a direction.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for (I'm already doing this) but I admit my first explanation wasn't very good, so I'll upvote anyway. I have updated the explanation by the way, you may want to check it.

Comment: Ok. I read your question again.Yes, it is bad idea to have Duplicate ID elements on a page but still you can access them separately in your case. If you will select `$('#firstWindow #windowContainer')` in jquery and perform any action, it will not effect `$('#secondWindow #windowContainer')` and `$('#thirdWindow #windowContainer')`. Try Here: http://jsfiddle.net/YHgrb/1/

Comment: So you can select each window's element by using its parent `DIV`  IDs(`firstWindow`, `secondWindow`, `thirdWindow`) in selector.

Comment: I thought I had tried this earlier to no avail but it actually does the trick. But I guess I'll run into more problems having duplicate ids anyway, so my question on which method to use to dynamically generate them still stands. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a **parameter in the URL** of the Ajax call to get the template to use your client side generated key.

A very rough (not secure) draft:

**On the server (template.php):**

```
<div id='<?= $_GET["container_key"] ?>' class='main-container'>
  ....
</div>
```

**Your ajax call:**

```
var containerKey = Math.random();
$.ajax("/template.php?container_key=" + containerKey, ....)
```

Use something better than `Math.random()` (like timestamps, guids, ...) to prevent collisions.

Comment: This is basically what I'd do if I'm going for method 1) (as described in the question), but I'm still undecided whether this is the best solution